# Vector allocator argument error while using SWIG generated python library

Tags: python, c++, list, vector, swig

I have used SWIG and generated a python library from C++ code and encountered the following error:

> TypeError: in method 'new_SpikeGeneratorFromVector', argument 1 of type 'std::vector< int,std::allocator< int > >'

I have included the interface file std_vector.i and stl.i and a few more that seemed necessary. When I pass an integer list to the function, I get the above error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve], and then show some code to reproduce the issue.  I'll guess you didn't use `%template`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I couldn't post my whole problem here due to a few confidentiality issues, but I should have been more, specific sorry for that. However, the problem was indeed the usage of template like you suggested. Now it works as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help:

```
/* File : example.i */

%module example

%{
#include "example.h"
%}

%include "std_vector.i"
namespace std {
    %template(IntVector)    vector<int>;
}

%include "example.h"

/*example.h*/
void my_func(std::vector<int> v) 
{
    for (int i=0; i<v.size(; i++))
        std::cout<<v[i]<<"\n";
}

/*in runme.py*/

import example
# call with a python list:
print example.my_func([1, 2, 3, 4])
#call with a python tuple:
print example.my_func((1, 2, 3, 4))
# ... or a wrapped std::vector<int>

v = example.IntVector(4)
for i in range(len(v)):
    v[i] = i + 1
print example.my_func(v)
```